# Does AEM Dispatcher sends the request headers as well to the Auth Checker Servlet of Permission Sensitive Caching

Tags: aem, dispatcher

I have a requirement of authoring a request first based on the passed Request Authorization Header and than providing the Servlet API response, now the servlet response will be cached on dispatcher, so need to enable Permission Sensitive Caching on my Dispatcher and need to create a Auth Checker Servlet which would be called by the Dispatcher before the dispatcher gives the Servlet Response from the Cache. Now, I wanted to know if the dispatcher, while making the HEAD call to the Auth Checker servlet, forward the Request Headers as well(which it receives in the client request) to the Auth Checker Servlet.

Comment: I have a requirement of *authorizing

Answer (score 0):

yes, all client headers will be passed to the Auth Checker Servlet including User-Agent, Host, Referer, Accept-*  headers,. etc.